# how to send large base64 string from mobile to server

Tags: java, rest, base64

In my project, I have to send an image as base64 string from mobile to server.

The probleam is, if the image size is huge i am getting the below error from my filter class

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)

wrapped by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.LogUIDFilter.doFilter(LogUIDFilter.java:99) [22 skipped]
```

Below is my filter class

```
public class LogUIDFilter implements Filter {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }


}
```

How to i send the huge base 64 text from mobile to server.Is there any other bettor approach to send image from mobile to server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: why on earth base64? that makes the image about 60% larger. Just use a good old bytestream

Comment: Seems that you are using GET request and pass base64 in the URL. You should use POST request and send it in the POST body.

Comment: @Lino, thanks for the suggestion.Is it possible to send bytestream from mobile to rest api

Comment: @Madhesh of course it is

Comment: @PavelMolchanov, No its post request.The problem is not with length its with stack memory based on the current stack size its allowing to upload

Comment: @Madhesh From the stack trace provided, RegEx is trying to parse your content. Why? Do you have any URL matching rules?

Comment: Be careful when accepting _large blobs_, as they may be used as an entry point of an attack by draining memory or storage resources.

Comment: @Lino The ratio of output bytes to input bytes is 4:3 (33% overhead), not 60%.

Comment: @PavelMolchanov, No i have to do some preprocessing for all requests.so i cannot ignore it

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO thanks for the correction, it is still too much to probably ever use Base64 to send something

Comment: It depends from the context. Using json is always heavier than using binary, but it is better to send json for rest api than binaries. If the file must be used in a field of json it must be in base64.

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo MARINO, but  if we pass the base64 in json we are getting the stack overflow error when the image size is more than 2kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to the size of the base64 image.

The problem is that You are using a regular expression in your code, I can imagine that you are testing the content of the base64 string.
The error is related to an long recursion done by the parser of that regular expression.

Regular expression containing some kind of paths (for example repetitive alternate paths like `(A|B)*`) are analyzed with recursive calls.
This can generate StackOverflowError if the parsed string is very long.

Comment: thanks, no i am not using any regular expression in code, i am getting this error in chain.filter(request, response). its the default filter.it may internally use the regular expression.

Comment: Have you access to all the code? The problem seems in the class LogUIDFilter. Is the code exactly as you copied in the question?

Comment: yes you are correct.We are using regular expression in another filter from that stackoverflow error is coming.here is my regex .Pattern clean = Pattern.compile(" \\s+ | ( \" (?: [^\"\\\\] | \\\\ . ) * \" ) ", Pattern.COMMENTS | Pattern.DOTALL).but i don't know why the base64 getting error with this regex

Comment: Only because the text to parse is too long. You really need to parse the base64?